# Prove that the function must be differentiable at $0$

Tags: calculus

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and set $f(x) = x^{2n}\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Prove that $f^{(k)}(0)$ exists for all $0 \leq k \leq n$ and $f^{(n)}(x)$ is not continuous at zero.

We first must show that the function is continuous $x = 0$. Then we have to prove that the left and right derivatives are equal at $0$. In other words, for $f'(x) =  x^{(2 n-2)} (2 n x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right))$ we must show continuity and differentiability around $f(0) = 0$ for example. I don't see a systematic way of proving this for all $k$, though. Inducting on $k$ might work.

Comment: Do you have to prove that it's continuous or not continuous... there's some contradiction here.

Comment: @peter.petrov Recall that the function may be continuous at a point but its $n$th derivative need not be.

Comment: The general form is $$f^{(n+1)}(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(x)-f^{(n)}(0)}{x-0}.$$ So using induction my not be so bad. If we assume that the previous derivative exists at $0$, then so must the next one.

Comment: But the 0th derivative is the function itself, no? Did you mean $1 \le k \le n$?

Comment: @peter.petrov No I didn't mean that. The 0th derivative is the function itself yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = P(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + Q(x)\cos(\frac{1}{x})$, for $P(x)$ and $Q(X)$ are polynomials.

Then $f'(x) = (P'(x)+\frac{Q(x)}{x^2})\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + (Q'(x)+\frac{P(x)}{x^2})\cos(\frac{1}{x})$.

We can show that $\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^m}$ has no limit when $x \to 0$. That means, in order $f'(x)$ to be continuous, each $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ must be in the form $x^2.p(x)$ and $x^2.q(x)$ respectively where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials.

So, say the minimum power of $x$ in $P(x)$ & $Q(x)$ is $u$ & $v$, respectively, then minimum powers of $P_1(x)$ & $Q_1(x)$ is $(v-2)$ & $(u-2)$,respectively, where

$f'(x) = P_1(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + Q_1(x)\cos(\frac{1}{x})$

In the OP, for the function $f(x)$ we have the polynomial $x^{2n}$, so for $f'(x)$, we have $x$ powers of $x^{2n-2}$.

Iteratively, replace $f'(x)$ to be the new $f(x)$, we conclude that $f(x)$ can be differentiable up to $n$ times as we remain $x^{2n-2n}$ (as $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$) where 0 to be the minimum power of $x$.

EDIT: PROOF OF DIFFERENTIABILITY UNDER CERTAIN SITUATION:

$f(x) = x^2.p(x)sin(\frac{1}{x}) + x^2.q(x)cos(\frac{1}{x}) \implies $

$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{ f(h)-f(0) }{h} = \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{ h^2.p(h)sin(\frac{1}{h}) + h^2.q(h)cos(\frac{1}{h}) }{h}$

$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0 } h.p(h)sin(\frac{1}{h}) + h.q(h)cos(\frac{1}{h}) = 0$ (since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are bounded and $h.p(h)$ and $h.q(h)$ goes to 0.

Comment: How does this prove that $f^{k}(0)$ exists?

Comment: @user19405892 as $f^{(k-1)}(x)$ has $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ with the at least  $x^2$ factor, for $1<k<n$, we can take the derivative.

Comment: But it is not defined at $x = 0$, so how can you conclude its $k$th derivative exists at $0$?

Comment: @user19405892 OK, so just one addition to prove $P(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + Q(x)\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ is differentiable at $x=0$ when polynomials have $x^2$ factors will be enough I think. I will add it.

Comment: It could have $0$ powers of $x$.

Comment: @user19405892 so do you say $x^0.sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is differentiable at $x = 0$?

Comment: What about continuity of $f^{(n)}(x)$ at $0$?

Comment: @user19405892 since $f^{(n)}(x)$ has polynomials starting from the order 0, (of the form $(...+bx^2+cx+d)\sin(\frac{1}{x})$), it is not continuous at 0. (this comes from the continuity of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$